# 404 redirecting to home

Tags: multisite, redirect, 404-error

I have a multisite network, and my theme has a custom `404.php`. On all the child sites this 404 handler is being correctly used, but on the primary site all 404s go back to the home page without touching my `404.php` at all.

And for once, this isn't the fault of the Redirection plugin! The problem is still there when Redirection is turned off (network-wide *and* on the specific site).

The problem isn't occurring on my local copy of the same site, but I can't find any difference in the configuration or plugins that could be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not occurring on your local installation: have you checked your webserver's configuration? Since the locally it works and it seems to work for the 404's of your subsites of your mainsite I would check this and make sure no plugins are activated during debugging this issue. If you use Apache with mod_rewrite you may want to check the logfiles (make sure it's enabled). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

put this code into a file named 404.php :

```
<?php
   header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
   header("Location:http://www.xxxxxx.tld");
?>
```

replace xxxxxx.tld by your domain name

and it will work like a charm

Comment: I wasn't trying to make the 404 redirect to home, I was trying to *prevent* it doing so.

Comment: then the problem must be inside your .htaccess file, have a look at it , if you won't understand the code paste it here

Comment: @Xufyan: I'd add an `exit;` statement after the header calls.